# How do you simulate typing using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click, typing, simulate

Like how the `click()` can be used to trigger a click event on an element, is there any way to simulate the typing of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to trigger the events associated with typing or do you want to append text to a container so that it looks like someone is typing?  If you're looking for the events, then @Nick is absolutely correct in suggesting the methods for triggering the event.  If the latter, you'll want to use a timer to replace the text/html of the container with successive substrings of your text.  You might be able to get a better effect by appending successive `span` elements containing each letter if the text is very long -- this would reduce flashing as the text gets replaced and the layout changes momentarily.

**EDIT**: I was going to add an example, but it turns out there's a plugin for that already: [jTypeWriter](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jTypeWriter).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, although all I need is for the textarea to be filled up (no need for any animation). I realized I can use innerHTML or what, silly me :)

Comment: It looks like jTypeWriter might be dead. At least, I can't find it anywhere. But I came across an alternative jQuery plugin that looks nice: [TypeType](http://iamdanfox.github.io/typetype/).

Answer (score 9):

You can use these events, depending on what you want:

- [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)
- [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)
- [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to simulate typing (i.e. including triggering the events and appending the text to an input or textarea element), you can use the jQuery simulate extended plugin:
http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext

Then you can use

```
$('input').simulate("key-sequence", {sequence: "This is a test", delay: 10});
```

to simulate the typing of the text `"This is a test"` with a 10ms delay between each key press.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: That library is abandoned according to its github page :(. Anyone knows a substitute?