# How do I use jQuery to automatically fill out a form in my website demo, as if a real person is actually typing?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, automation

I have a website with registration forms. I'm going to be demoing the website onscreen, and would like to have the forms fill themselves out, as if a person was manually typing in the form data.

Is there a relatively simple way to do this with jQuery?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578211/how-do-you-simulate-typing-using-jquery), it looks like there’s a jQuery plug-in called [jTypeWriter](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jTypeWriter) that might do what you’re looking for.

But [as Robert says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202696/20578), the Selenium IDE plug-in for Firefox lets you record and play back browser interactions — assuming you’re demoing from your own computer, that’s probably easier than writing a bunch of jQuery code.

Answer (score 4):

I would instead look at the [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: Looks like cool stuff. Going to try it out and get back. Thanks guys.

Comment: Selenium IDE powerful great - will definitely use it on another project someday - but jTypeWriter fit my simple needs for now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution:

```
//declare string to write,
//then split it at each letter,
//then get the total number of letters,
//declare a starting index of zero,
//then set a timer for an interval
var string  = 'hello there',
    letters = string.split(''),
    total   = letters.length,
    index   = 0,
    $ele    = $('input'),//this should be changed to target the form input you want to type into
    timer   = setInterval(function () {

        //check if there are any more letters
        if (index < total) {

            //if there are more letters then add the next letter to the input
            $ele.val(function () {
                return $ele.val() + letters[(index++)];
            });

        //if there are no more letters then clear the interval so it stops running
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 500);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pCVE6/

Answer (score 1):

What about a Macro PlugIn? 
 If you use Firefox, you can check out this: [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/).