# jquery display string character by character

Tags: jquery, string, recursion, character

I want to create a jquery script that can write down a string inside a div character by character as if somebody would be typing it as the user is looking at the page.

I assume this would work with a recursive function using settimeout.

Help me with this please. Thanks.

Comment: This topic has some examples and some links to some plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578211/how-do-you-simulate-typing-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write one yourself.

- Make use of `setInterval()`
- Store a message in the array and pop the words / characters one by one
- Clear the interval when you're done

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89xF6/2/)

**jQuery:**

```
// Consturct a message, transform it to an array using .split() and reverse it
// If you want to print out one word at a time instead of a character at a time
// Change .split('') to .split(' ')
var $message = 'This is a message to be rendered'.split('').reverse();

// Set the frequency of your 'pops'
var $timeout = 1000;

var outputSlowly = setInterval(function() {

    // Add text to the target element
    $('#target').append($message.pop());

    // No more characters - exit
    if ($message.length === 0) {            
        clearInterval(outputSlowly);   
    }

}, $timeout);
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="target"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Typewriter available here: https://github.com/chadselph/jquery-typewriter.

You can see the demo which is on the repo itself.

Here is an example of how it works:

```
$('.someselector').typewrite({
'delay': 100, 
'extra_char': '', 
'trim': true, 
'callback': null
});
```